# Where are my TFS 2010 dashboards?

Tags: tfs

I have a project portal set up, and under dashboards in the left-hand nav, I see "My Dashboard" and "Project Dashboard". Apparently there are other dashboards available, like Burndown, Quality, Bugs, Test, and Build, but they aren't available to me.

Any idea how I can access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens if you select a project type that doesn't support these modules (use Agile or Scrum) or if the features aren't enabled on the SharePoint site where the project portal is hosted.

Go to Site Settings > Site Collection Features.  Make sure Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Web Part Collection is enabled.

Go back to Settings, Go to Site Actions and Manage Site Features.  Check if the Agile Dashboards with Excel are enabled.